problem to go to the headline in a Wilson Resume/CV template
I give a practical example using Wilson Resume/CV template. I am using the following template for my Curriculum Vitae and in the item selected in red, which is too long, I would like to go to the headline. I've tried adding the command \newline or \ but couldn't get any useful results

https://www.latextemplates.com/actions/action_download_template?template=wilson-resume-cv&type=Preview+Template+PDF
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EMPLOYMENT HISTORY SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Employment History}

\job
{Sep 2011 -}{Present}
{Lehman Brothers, 1234 Mario Park, San Francisco, CA, United States}
{http://www.lehmanbrothers.com}
{Senior Developer / Technical Team Lead}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis elementum nec dolor sed sagittis. Cras justo lorem, volutpat mattis lacus vel, consequat aliquam quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.\\
\rule{0mm}{5mm}\textbf{Technologies:} Ruby on Rails 2.3, Amazon EC2, NoSQL data stores, memcached, collaborative matching, Facebook Graph API.}

And in structure.tex the \job comand is:
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   JOB COMMAND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\job}[6]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2cm} \= \kill
\textbf{#1} \> \href{#4}{#3} \\
\textbf{#2} \>\+ \textit{#5} \\
\begin{minipage}{\smallertextwidth}
\vspace{2mm}
#6
\end{minipage}
\end{tabbing}
\vspace{2mm}
}

